# localForage.setDriver is not a function, using react redux session

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I just started using react-redux-session. I installed the same using npm and implemented the code in my react app. However there is an error that is coming up, `localForage.setDriver is not a function`. I even installed the dependencies (`localforage`) for it, but still the error.

Am I missing some necessary step? Below is my component where I am calling it.

```
import App from './containers/App';
import Routes from './Routes';
import appReducer from './reducers';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { sessionService } from 'redux-react-session';

let store = createStore(appReducer);
const options = { refreshOnCheckAuth: true, redirectPath: '/login', driver: 
'LOCALSTORAGE' };

sessionService.initSessionService(store, options);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App>
                <Routes />
            </App>
    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>,

document.getElementById('main')
);
```

Package Details:

```
"redux-react-session": "^2.1.0"<br/>
"localforage": "^1.5.2",

"webpack": "^3.5.6",<br/>
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
```

Any advice would be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: I also have the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: No @Sudhir, alternately using COOKIES